# BeautifulSoup trying get info from next page

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import xlrd
import re

def get_some_pages(pages):
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
  params = {'catalogNodeId': 313, 'pageNumber' : pages}
  url = 'https://list.szlcsc.com/catalog/431.html'
  china = pd.DataFrame()
  for page in range(1, pages+1):
    params['page'] = page
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    time.sleep(10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    all_cat_list = soup.find_all('tr', {'class' :'no-tj-tr add-cart-tr'})
    for cat_list in all_cat_list:
      list_cat = []
      name = cat_list.select_one('div.two-tit').select_one('a').text.strip()
      link = cat_list.select_one('div.two-tit').select_one('a').get('href')
      kolvo = cat_list.select_one('div.stock-nums-js').select_one('span').text.strip()
      price = cat_list.select_one('div.price-warp-local').select_one('span').get('orderprice')
      row = {'name': name, 'link': link, 'kolvo': kolvo, 'price' : price, 'rub': float(price)*1.6}
      china = pd.concat([china, pd.DataFrame([row])]) 
  return china.reset_index(drop=True)

get_some_pages(3)
```

but as a result I get 3 identical rows of 30:

| index | name | link | kolvo | price | rub |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100nF -20%~+50% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/111476.html | 36260 | 0.207243 | 0.3315888 |
| 31 | 100nF -20%~+50% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/111476.html | 36260 | 0.207243 | 0.3315888 |
| 61 | 100nF -20%~+50% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/111476.html | 36260 | 0.207243 | 0.3315888 |
| 9 | 100nF ±5% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/111504.html | 6220 | 0.358433 | 0.5734928 |
| 39 | 100nF ±5% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/111504.html | 6220 | 0.358433 | 0.5734928 |
| 69 | 100nF ±5% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/111504.html | 6220 | 0.358433 | 0.5734928 |
| 18 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/165845.html | 4710 | 0.21287 | 0.340592 |
| 48 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/165845.html | 4710 | 0.21287 | 0.340592 |
| 78 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/165845.html | 4710 | 0.21287 | 0.340592 |
| 13 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/180136.html | 4580 | 0.195823 | 0.3133168 |
| 43 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/180136.html | 4580 | 0.195823 | 0.3133168 |
| 73 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/180136.html | 4580 | 0.195823 | 0.3133168 |
| 7 | 10nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/180497.html | 3300 | 0.227695 | 0.364312 |
| 37 | 10nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/180497.html | 3300 | 0.227695 | 0.364312 |
| 67 | 10nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/180497.html | 3300 | 0.227695 | 0.364312 |
| 11 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/180498.html | 16270 | 0.510444 | 0.8167104000000001 |
| 41 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/180498.html | 16270 | 0.510444 | 0.8167104000000001 |
| 71 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/180498.html | 16270 | 0.510444 | 0.8167104000000001 |
| 25 | 100nF -20%~+80% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/2261735.html | 5890 | 0.657599 | 1.0521584000000002 |
| 55 | 100nF -20%~+80% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/2261735.html | 5890 | 0.657599 | 1.0521584000000002 |
| 85 | 100nF -20%~+80% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/2261735.html | 5890 | 0.657599 | 1.0521584000000002 |
| 14 | 22pF ±5% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/2262295.html | 19645 | 0.577527 | 0.9240432000000001 |
| 44 | 22pF ±5% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/2262295.html | 19645 | 0.577527 | 0.9240432000000001 |
| 74 | 22pF ±5% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/2262295.html | 19645 | 0.577527 | 0.9240432000000001 |
| 21 | 470nF ±10% 25V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254295.html | 4940 | 0.292084 | 0.46733440000000004 |
| 51 | 470nF ±10% 25V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254295.html | 4940 | 0.292084 | 0.46733440000000004 |
| 81 | 470nF ±10% 25V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254295.html | 4940 | 0.292084 | 0.46733440000000004 |
| 28 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254300.html | 720 | 0.258613 | 0.4137808 |
| 58 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254300.html | 720 | 0.258613 | 0.4137808 |
| 88 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254300.html | 720 | 0.258613 | 0.4137808 |
| 10 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254301.html | 4600 | 0.161857 | 0.2589712 |
| 40 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254301.html | 4600 | 0.161857 | 0.2589712 |
| 70 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254301.html | 4600 | 0.161857 | 0.2589712 |
| 8 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254302.html | 4500 | 0.335978 | 0.5375648000000001 |
| 38 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254302.html | 4500 | 0.335978 | 0.5375648000000001 |
| 68 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254302.html | 4500 | 0.335978 | 0.5375648000000001 |
| 19 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254303.html | 1520 | 0.251345 | 0.402152 |
| 49 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254303.html | 1520 | 0.251345 | 0.402152 |
| 79 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254303.html | 1520 | 0.251345 | 0.402152 |
| 23 | 1uF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254305.html | 2600 | 0.153199 | 0.24511840000000001 |
| 53 | 1uF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254305.html | 2600 | 0.153199 | 0.24511840000000001 |
| 83 | 1uF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254305.html | 2600 | 0.153199 | 0.24511840000000001 |
| 15 | 220nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254307.html | 10880 | 0.219332 | 0.3509312 |
| 45 | 220nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254307.html | 10880 | 0.219332 | 0.3509312 |
| 75 | 220nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254307.html | 10880 | 0.219332 | 0.3509312 |
| 4 | 30pF ±5% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254310.html | 2680 | 0.162608 | 0.26017280000000004 |
| 34 | 30pF ±5% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254310.html | 2680 | 0.162608 | 0.26017280000000004 |
| 64 | 30pF ±5% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/254310.html | 2680 | 0.162608 | 0.26017280000000004 |
| 27 | 10uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/2886487.html | 3551 | 1.0318 | 1.6508800000000001 |
| 57 | 10uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/2886487.html | 3551 | 1.0318 | 1.6508800000000001 |
| 87 | 10uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/2886487.html | 3551 | 1.0318 | 1.6508800000000001 |
| 16 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/358988.html | 1040 | 0.181272 | 0.2900352 |
| 46 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/358988.html | 1040 | 0.181272 | 0.2900352 |
| 76 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/358988.html | 1040 | 0.181272 | 0.2900352 |
| 29 | 100nF ±20% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/383449.html | 10040 | 0.240469 | 0.3847504 |
| 59 | 100nF ±20% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/383449.html | 10040 | 0.240469 | 0.3847504 |
| 89 | 100nF ±20% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/383449.html | 10040 | 0.240469 | 0.3847504 |
| 2 | 100nF ±10% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/383460.html | 20520 | 0.297071 | 0.4753136 |
| 32 | 100nF ±10% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/383460.html | 20520 | 0.297071 | 0.4753136 |
| 62 | 100nF ±10% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/383460.html | 20520 | 0.297071 | 0.4753136 |
| 12 | 100nF ±10% 100V | https://item.szlcsc.com/456484.html | 1770 | 0.775241 | 1.2403856 |
| 42 | 100nF ±10% 100V | https://item.szlcsc.com/456484.html | 1770 | 0.775241 | 1.2403856 |
| 72 | 100nF ±10% 100V | https://item.szlcsc.com/456484.html | 1770 | 0.775241 | 1.2403856 |
| 22 | 150pF ±5% 100V | https://item.szlcsc.com/456507.html | 50 | 0.377623 | 0.6041968 |
| 52 | 150pF ±5% 100V | https://item.szlcsc.com/456507.html | 50 | 0.377623 | 0.6041968 |
| 82 | 150pF ±5% 100V | https://item.szlcsc.com/456507.html | 50 | 0.377623 | 0.6041968 |
| 6 | 3.3nF ±10% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/456540.html | 36430 | 0.312615 | 0.500184 |
| 36 | 3.3nF ±10% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/456540.html | 36430 | 0.312615 | 0.500184 |
| 66 | 3.3nF ±10% 63V | https://item.szlcsc.com/456540.html | 36430 | 0.312615 | 0.500184 |
| 0 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/85943.html | 600 | 0.184491 | 0.2951856 |
| 30 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/85943.html | 600 | 0.184491 | 0.2951856 |
| 60 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/85943.html | 600 | 0.184491 | 0.2951856 |
| 17 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/95906.html | 3695 | 0.596727 | 0.9547632 |
| 47 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/95906.html | 3695 | 0.596727 | 0.9547632 |
| 77 | 1uF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/95906.html | 3695 | 0.596727 | 0.9547632 |
| 3 | 10nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/95911.html | 9560 | 0.180853 | 0.28936480000000003 |
| 33 | 10nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/95911.html | 9560 | 0.180853 | 0.28936480000000003 |
| 63 | 10nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/95911.html | 9560 | 0.180853 | 0.28936480000000003 |
| 5 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/95915.html | 14680 | 0.197489 | 0.3159824 |
| 35 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/95915.html | 14680 | 0.197489 | 0.3159824 |
| 65 | 100nF ±20% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/95915.html | 14680 | 0.197489 | 0.3159824 |
| 24 | 10nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/985416.html | 2720 | 0.137334 | 0.21973440000000002 |
| 54 | 10nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/985416.html | 2720 | 0.137334 | 0.21973440000000002 |
| 84 | 10nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/985416.html | 2720 | 0.137334 | 0.21973440000000002 |
| 20 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/985417.html | 2220 | 0.135642 | 0.21702720000000003 |
| 50 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/985417.html | 2220 | 0.135642 | 0.21702720000000003 |
| 80 | 100nF ±10% 50V | https://item.szlcsc.com/985417.html | 2220 | 0.135642 | 0.21702720000000003 |
| 26 | 1uF ±10% 100V | https://item.szlcsc.com/985421.html | 4450 | 0.525851 | 0.8413615999999999 |
| 56 | 1uF ±10% 100V | https://item.szlcsc.com/985421.html | 4450 | 0.525851 | 0.8413615999999999 |
| 86 | 1uF ±10% 100V | https://item.szlcsc.com/985421.html | 4450 | 0.525851 | 0.8413615999999999 |

Comment: Probably you don't change the page and you are scraping the same page every time.

Comment: page needs `'pageNumber'` but you set `params['page'] = page`. But there can be different problem: page sends it as `POST` but you send it as `GET`. And it may need also other values in `params` which you should as `data=` instead of `params=`. It may need also other headers - ie. `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'` because page sends it as `AJAX`

Comment: it uses JavaScript to load new data from `https://list.szlcsc.com/products/list` as JSON and later JavaScript replace values on page - but `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. You should download data directly as JSON and you will no need BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems.

Main problem is that page uses `JavaScript` (`AJAX`) to get data as `JSON` data from different url `https://list.szlcsc.com/products/list` and later it replaces elements in `HTML` - but `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`.

But you can use `requests` to get directly `JSON` data without using `BeautifulSoup`.

It has to send `POST` instead of `GET`, and it needs `pageNumber` instead of `page`. And it has to send it as `form` data (using `data=`) instead of sending it as url's arguments (using `params=`).

To make sure I added also header `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'` which servers used to recognize `AJAX`.

`JSON` has many other values and I used `productID` to check if elements are different.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
#import time
#import random

def get_some_pages(pages):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Mobile Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }
    
    params = {
        'catalogNodeId': 313,
        'pageNumber': 0
    }
    
    url = 'https://list.szlcsc.com/products/list'
    
    # --- before loop ---
    
    all_products = []

    # --- loop ---
    
    for page in range(1, pages+1):
        print('page:', page)
        
        params['pageNumber'] = page
        
        res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=params)
        data = res.json()
              
        all_products += data['productRecordList']
        
        #time.sleep(random.randint(3, 10))  # to behave like real human
        
    # --- after loop ---
    
    return pd.DataFrame(all_products)

# --- main ---

df = get_some_pages(3)

df['productId'] = df['productId'].astype(int)

print(print(df[['productId', 'productName', 'totalStockNumber']].sort_values('productId')))
```

Result:

```
    productId      productName  totalStockNumber
66       1876    10nF ±10% 50V           5222300
8        1877   100nF ±10% 16V          18869000
63       1902  1pF ±0.25pF 50V           6838500
62       1906     20pF ±5% 50V           6601500
28       1933   100nF ±20% 50V           2125200
..        ...              ...               ...
68     370208   100nF ±10% 16V           5894100
12     483556   100nF ±10% 50V          26595000
55     486113   100nF ±10% 50V           7884900
37     631473    22uF ±20% 25V          10163940
51     727067   100nF ±10% 25V           6119900
```